# How to stop Javascript function being defined twice in ASP.NET User Control

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I have a User Control in ASP.NET. It contains a script block, which defines a function for use on the client.  If I include two of the controls on the same page, the function will be defined twice (I think - not that familiar with Javascript).  Is there a way to stop this, perhaps some kind of code along the lines 'if exists fn() blah blah'?

Kind wishes ~ Patrick

Answer (score 3):

Yup. If you are defining a js function in global scope then it will become a property of the window object. So you can write your function like this:

```
<script>
if (!window.myFunction) {
    myFunction = function myFunction(..any params..) {
        // do some stuff
    };
};
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the `ClientScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptInclude` method to specify the script for a control. So that, you can include multiple controls with the same script. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kx145dw2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: That looks like what I need, but I am confused by the Type parameter.  In the example, isn't the type Page?  (I would have thought the type needed to be something representing a Javascript script.)

Comment: It is the type of the user control that you are using. You should use the `typeof` operator or the `GetType()` method to get this.

Comment: I have just been playing about with this, and if I place the Javascript function in a separate file, included in the page header, then you only get one copy of the function anyway, so I don't appear to need either solution above. Am I missing something here?